# How to combine two string in twig?

Tags: twig

I want to do something like this:

```
{% set c=a+b %}
```

Where *a* and *b* are strings.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 153, accepted):

The way to do it is:

```
{% set c = a ~ b %}
```

Comment: How do you concatenate 'some text with a' `stringOrVariable`?

Comment: In PHP we use dot `.` to concatenate strings or variables, in Twig we use `~`. Example: `{{ "Hello" ~ a }}` to concatenate a string and a variable. For variables you can do `{{ a ~ b ~ c }}` The `~` replaces the dot `.`

Answer (score 20):

Use the "~" operator. This will concatenate your two strings. The "+" operator cannot be used to combine strings.

You would get this:

```
{% set c=a~b %}
```

More info:
The "+" operator: Adds two objects together (the operands are casted to numbers).

Answer (score 11):

You can use:

{{ "Hello " ~ name ~ "!" }}

Answer (score 0):

**A clearer example for the {% block page %}...{% endblock %}:**

```
{% block page %}
    {% set page = page | merge({
    "title"       : branchName,
    "description" : "This description has "~branchName~" as its title"
    }) %}
    {{ parent() }}
{% endblock %}
```

**A clearer example for the {% block content %}...{% endblock %}:**

```
{% block content %}
    This is just a sample string for {{ branchName }} that needs no concatenation
{% endblock %}
```