# Twig - Append string data to same variable

Tags: twig

How would you append more data to the same variable in Twig? For example, this is what I'm trying to do in Twig:

```
var data = "foo";
data += 'bar';
```

I have figured out that `~` appends strings together in Twig. When I try `{% set data ~ 'foo' %}` I get an error in Twig.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The `~` operator does not perform assignment, which is the likely cause of the error.

Instead, you need to assign the appended string back to the variable:

```
{% set data = data ~ 'foo' %}
```

See also: [How to combine two string in twig?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10470328/how-to-combine-two-string-in-twig)

Comment: This won't work `{% set itemClasses = 'item ' ~ loop.first ? 'active' %}`, but this will do `{% set itemClasses = 'item ' ~ (loop.first ? 'active') %}`

Answer (score 0):

Displaying dynamically in twig

```
{% for Resp in test.TestRespuestasA %}        
    {% set name = "preg_A_" ~ Resp.id %}
    {% set name_aux = "preg_A_comentario" ~ Resp.id %}
    <li>{{ form_row(attribute(form, name)) }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also define a custom filter like Liquid's [`|append`](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/append/) filter in your Twig instance which does the same thing.

```
$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('./path/to/views/dir');
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);

...
...

$twig->addFilter(new Twig_SimpleFilter('append', function($val, $append) {
    return $val . $append;
}));
```

Resulting in the following markup:

```
{% set pants = 'I\'m wearing stretchy pants!' %}
{% set part2 = ' and they\'re friggin\' comfy!' %}
{% set pants = pants|append(part2) %}

{{ pants }}

{# result: I'm wearing stretchy pants! and they're friggin' comfy! #}
```

IMHO I find the above sample more intuitive than the `~` combinator, especially when working on a shared codebase where people new to the syntax might get a bit mixed up.